# get the value of a given key from json array of objects in meteor

Tags: json, meteor

This meteor code has menuItems to populate a li in the template. When an item is clicked, I need to get the value of the "login" key from the object that was clicked.
I could not use `menuItems.find();` because it is not a mongo collection.
I could not create a json object `JSON.parse(menuItem)` because menuItem is undefined in the console.
I could not think of what to google for either.

Thanks

```html
Template.mainMenu.helpers({
  menuItems: [
    {menuItem: "task1", login: false},
    {menuItem: "task2", login: true},
    {menuItem: "task3", login: true},
    {menuItem: "task4", login: true},
    {menuItem: "task5", login: true},
    {menuItem: "task6", login: true},
    {menuItem: "task7", login: false},
    {menuItem: "task8", login: false},
    {menuItem: "task9", login: false}
  ]
});

Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function (event) {
    var item = $(event.currentTarget).data('value');

    var isLogin = what is the value of login for this "item"
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know how to approach it in meteor. Build a json object, or is there a meteor way of do it, or what not... Don't know even what to google for :) downVoted!? Sigh

Comment: You cannot do `menuItems.find();` not because it's not a Mongo collection but because it's an array that only has numeric keys, and still none has a value of type function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so basic, you should have seen the answer in first 100 lines of docs. Nevertheless, let me explain it a bit.

You're using a helper to put the data into `li` elements. This helper returns an array of objects, so you can use it as an iterable in your template, i.e. use `each` block:

```
{{#each menuItems}}
  <li class="menuItem">{{menuItem}} {{login}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Something like that.

Then, you have an event handler which listens to every click event on every element that has `menuItem` class. Think of it as of jQuery's event handler, so, in jQuery, you would write it in a way like that:

```
$('.menuItem').each(function () {...});
```

Within the function you pass into `each` method, you can access the iterable's element through `this` keyword. So, for example, you want to access `login` property of any of iterable's items. You could do that like

```
$('.menuItem').each(function () {
  console.log(this.login);
});
```

Let's go back to Meteor. In event handler, you can use the same approach to access any property of the object. `this` will refer to the element as user clicked. So, the answer is

```
Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function () {
    const item = this;

    // do whatever you need with this object
  }
});
```

Template event handler function has two arguments, one for event and one for the template. You may need them, but in this particular case, both are unnecessary, hence no arguments supplied to the function assigned as a handler to the click event.

---

Just keep in mind that `each` block in the template creates a new nested context, and in this context, `this` refers to the item of whatever `each` block iterates over. This is why you can refer to properties of each object in your JSON via helpers:

```
{{#each menuItems}}
  <li class="menuItem">{{menuItem}} {{login}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

You can see that you don't have `menuItem` or `login` helpers but they work anyway. In fact, this is a short form of

```
{{#each menuItems}}
  <li class="menuItem">{{this.menuItem}} {{this.login}}</li>
{{/each}}
```